# Complex square root in .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

Having troubles with C# and its square root computation. `Math.sqrt` doesn't support negative arguments.

```
using System.Numerics;
```

and consiquently,

> Complex

class,
works only under .Net 4.0 and higher. Due to project restrictions I can use only .Net 3.5

Is there any workaround available for this problem? Any suggestions how to get complex square root in .Net 3.5?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923247/square-root-of-negative-numbers

Comment: a simple reading of this post leads to use Complex.Sqrt only available in .Net 4.0

Comment: [Download the source code.](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d0dc5fc099946adc1035b34a8b1f6042eddb0c75/src/System.Runtime.Numerics/src/System/Numerics/Complex.cs)

Comment: You'll need a library for complex arithmetic that works on .NET 3.5. Supplying such a library is out of scope for SO.

Comment: @PatrickHofman , so I am supposed to copy whole class from github? 
Erm, if you meant this solution, - I will try, but not sure mentioned 

`using System.Globalization;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;`

are usable in .Net 3.5

Comment: Have you try this one: http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/ ?

Comment: Then remove all that you don't need and see if you get it working.

Comment: @currarpickt, will try your solution, and Patrick's one. Thanks everyone for help!